# Provide an example to show that $S$ may not necessarily be a unique factorisation domain when $R$ is a unique factorisation domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $R$ and $S$ be integral domains, and suppose that $\phi:R \rightarrow S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism. Provide an example to show that $S$ may not necessarily be a unique factorisation domain when $R$ is a unique factorisation domain.

My example: Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $S = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Both $R$ and $S$ are integral domains. Consider the surjective ring homomorphism $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ defined by $\phi(a+ bi) = a+b\sqrt{-5}$. $R$ is a unique factorisation domain, but $S$ is not a unique factorisation domain.

Comment: $(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=(0,0)$\in $R$, so $R$ is not integral. Also, your $S$ is a UFD

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have changed my $S$. I am trying to find a R that maps to $S$ but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen does it work if i consider $Z[i]$ to $Z[\sqrt{-5}]$?

Comment: Did you even *try* to check your map $\mathbf Z[i] \rightarrow \mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a *ring homomorphism*? A homomorphism is not just symbol-pushing.

Answer (score 1):

The ring of integers $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ of $\mathbf Q[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD.

For instance, $6$ has two decompositions:
$$6=2\cdot 3=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$$
and the factors on the left hand side are not associated to any factor on the right hand side, since their norms are different: $N(2)=4, N(3)=9$ and $N((1+\sqrt{-5})=N(1-\sqrt{-5})=6$

However  $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$  is isomorphic to the quotient $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+5)$. So $R=\mathbf Z[x]$ is a UFD, but $S=\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+5)$ is not.

Comment: Hi, can you explain more about your answer. I don't quite understand your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @123: I added some details. Is that clearer?